# Terminal Warning of command not found: nvm

Tags: terminal, nvm

I installed nvm, used it and afterwards I uninstalled it again because I didn't need it anymore (used homebrew installation of node instead). Unfortunately, my Terminal now shows me the Command not found error whenever I am executing any command (just a cd command already gives me the error). I can't find out how to remove those warnings and would greatly apprechiate any help.

Those are the error messages shown:

```
load-nvmrc:1: command not found: nvm
load-nvmrc:2: command not found: nvm_find_nvmrc
load-nvmrc:12: command not found: nvm
```